# wmii on Debian not working

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, window-manager, debian-wheezy

I did a fresh install of Debian 7.1 headless, and installed wmii along with several X packages.  Wmii opens when I run startx, but not completely, and it is unusable.  Although I'm fairly proficient with Linux, I've never used wmii before, so I can't exactly tell you what it *isn't* doing.  I can move the mouse and drag vertical lines from the edges of the screen.  Clicking and holding the bottom left of the screen on the "1" gets a small popup that says "Delete".  There is a functioning time and date display on the bottom right of the screen, along with some numbers which I don't know the meaning of.  My keyboard has no meta key, so I modified `wmiirc` to use Mod1 (Alt) instead of the Debian default, Mod4.

This isn't the first time I've tried to install wmii on Debian - the same thing happened before on a different installation.  Is the wmii package just completely broken in Wheezy, or is there some configuration trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem was that I was starting wmii as root.